# Bouncycastle and PKCS #1 v2.1, Signing with RSASSA-PSS & Encrypting with AES CBC with RSAES-OAEP

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, signing

After countless hours spent with this library I still can't get it work.

I want to send smime messages with the bouncy castle library, signed with the RSASSA-PSS, encrypted with AES, where the key transport should be RSAES-OAEP, all P1#v2.1

Signer first, this is how it's created:

```
SMIMESignedGenerator gen = new SMIMESignedGenerator();
            SignerInfoGenerator signer
            = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder()
            .setProvider("BC")
            .build("SHA256withRSAAndMGF1", pk.getPrivateKey(), pk.getCertificate()
            );
gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(signer);
        gen.addCertificates(certStore);
        MimeMultipart mmp = gen.generate(message);
```

So now when it should be signed, encrypting and using OAEP padding:

```
    OutputEncryptor enc = new BcCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES192_CBC).build();
        SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator gen = new SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator();

        for (X509Certificate nCert : certs) {
                RecipientInfoGenerator keyTransportRecipient = 
                new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(nCert).setProvider("BC").
setAlgorithmMapping(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption, "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding");
                gen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(keyTransportRecipient);
        }
                MimeBodyPart encryptedMimeBodyPart = gen.generate(message, enc);
```

I could not find the proper setAlgorithmMapping() description, so I did try following combinations:

```
.setAlgorithmMapping(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption, "RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding");
.setAlgorithmMapping(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption, "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding");
.setAlgorithmMapping(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSAES_OAEP, "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA56AndMGF1Padding");
```

btw, can anyone please explain, what exactly this pattern means here -  "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding"? 
Am I right if the first param is the public key algorithm, second "ECB" is I suppose ECB AES mode? (I tried CBC mode also, but got no such algorithm exception, tried NONE also) And the last ("OAEPWithSHA56AndMGF1Padding") is apparently OAEP p1#v2.1, which I actually want.

So, at this point messages should be signed & encrypted.
When I check my mailbox now (with **Thunderbird**), it says: "Thunderbird cannot decrypt this message", "The sender encrypted this message to you using one of your digital certificates, however Thunderbird was not able to find this certificate and corresponding private key."

But, when I was signing with old signer

```
build("SHA256withRSAEncryption", pk.getPrivateKey(), pk.getCertificate()
```

and used the old key transpport scheme, which was

```
setProvider("BC").setAlgorithmMapping(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption, "RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding");
```

everything worked fine. So apparently my self-signed x509 certificate is not the problem here, please correct me if I'm whong here.

I also tested it with **Outlook (2013)**

*Old scheme (SHA256withRSAEncryption signing + PKCS1Padding key transport)* -> Everything is fine.

*New scheme (SHA256withRSAAndMGF1 signing + RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding)* -> "Your Digital ID name cannot be found by the underlying security system" Error.

At this point I have no idea what's is actually wrong.
This is how I create certificate with openssl:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -out certificate.cer -keyout private.key -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:32 -passin pass:mypass -utf8 -config _openssl.cfg -extensions v3_req
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -name "testname" -inkey private.key -in certificate.cer
```

Comment: "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding" -> RSA, the cipher to use (OAEP can be used with other ciphers), ECB -> should actually be None, historical artefact, mode of encryption for RSA (nothing to do with AES in this string) and OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding is OAEP configured using SHA256 for MGF1. As SHA-1 is the default and is actually safe for use here I'd use that instead of SHA-256 and try that. There are plenty of cases where the hash change is the issue.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if nobody else answers, try the BC development mailing list instead (and report back here!).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the choise of hash function is not mine, I have to use sha256

Answer (score 3):

Giving an AlgorithmIdentifier for RSA-OAEP to the OutputEncryptor is the wrong way. It will (at least for me) result in an error like this:

```
 ... no such algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.7 for provider BC
```

If you want to use AES and RSA-OAEP then you have to assign AES to the `OutputEncryptor` (who is responsible for symmetric encryption)
and RSA-OAEP to the `RecipientInfoGenerator` (who is responsible for key encryption respectively asymmetric encryption).

Here is the code:

(The definition of the `OAEPParameterSpec` was already correctly explained in a previous post here).

```
// Note that at JcaAlgorithmParametersConverter is available since BC 1.50.
JcaAlgorithmParametersConverter paramsConverter = new JcaAlgorithmParametersConverter();
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameters = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec(
        "SHA-256"), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
AlgorithmIdentifier idRsaOaep = paramsConverter.getAlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSAES_OAEP, oaepParameters);

SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator encryptor = new SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator();

// Assign OAEPParameterSpec and an instance of X509Certificate to the RecipientInfoGenerator.
// prov is an instance of BouncyCastleProvider.
encryptor.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(certificate, idRsaOaep)
        .setProvider(prov));

// Use an OutputEncryptor with AES.
OutputEncryptor outputEncryptor = new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES128_CBC)
        .setProvider(prov)
        .build();

// Do encryption (were plaintextMsg is a MimeMessage instance).
MimeBodyPart payload = encryptor.generate(plaintextMsg, outputEncryptor);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved your problem. At least in my case it's working.
For the AlgorithmIdentifier for PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSAES_OAEP I added the following lines of code:

```
pubilc AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgo() {

        JcaAlgorithmParametersConverter paramsConverter = new JcaAlgorithmParametersConverter();
        OAEPParameterSpec oaepSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-256"), new PSource.PSpecified(new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
    return paramsConverter.getAlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSAES_OAEP, oaepSpec);
}
```

With this parameterized AlgorithmIdentifier you can now encrypt you message:

```
AlgorithmIdentifier algo = getAlgo();
    SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator encrypter = new SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator();
    RecipientInfoGenerator keyTransportRecipient = 
                            new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(cert).setProvider("BC").setAlgorithmMapping(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSAES_OAEP, "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding");

encrypter.generate(bodyPart, new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(algo).setProvider("BC").build());                            encrypter.addRecipientInfoGenerator(keyTransportRecipient);
```

Did you have any success on the signing issue? In my case, Outlook says the signature is not valid.

Comment: Still working on it. Got it to work thanks to David Hook (BC dev) [here](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/PKCS-1-v2-1-Signing-with-RSASSA-PSS-amp-Encrypting-with-AES-CBC-with-RSAES-OAEP-td4658634.html), but having the same problem as you at this moment, outlook says that there must be an error on the signature layer. In thunderbird it can't even open email, well at least it's some progress. If I figure it out, I'll message here! Thanks

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. When you click the signature exclamation mark in outlook -> Details...->Show details-> swith to the Details tab, there will be "Unknown (1.2.840.113549.1.9.52)" field, which is the CMSAlgorithmProtect in Signature block, which causes the problem with Outlook, at least I'm 99% sure it does. Didn't fix it still, but the problem is probably here.

Comment: I get another error message when I click on the Details tab. For me the message is something like 'This message has potenitally been modified'.

Comment: Yeah, I have this one also.

Comment: Sill, no progress on the signing issue, I guess?

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error and no ideas why. If outlook supports OAEP, it probably should support PSS mode also?

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but I think OAEP and PSS are two separate things, so it could be that OAEP is not supported by Outlook, but I doubt it.
Funnily enough, my signed message (with RSASSA-PSS) can be correctly verified by Bouncy Castle itself. So, if everyone would you Bouncy Castle, there would be no problem. :)

Comment: They are both parts of the PKCS #2.1 standard, it probably would not make sence for Microsoft to implement oaep and leave pss, but what do I know :) I only wish microsoft were providing more debug output for this error. Did you try some alternative email clients?

Comment: Yes, I tried Thunderbird, but without success => Same error message ("Invalid signature")

Comment: Nothing new on this issue?

Comment: nope... But whenever I hear "bouncycastle" now, I just want to kill myself. That's something new I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think is that most S/MIME clients do not support
RSASSA-PSS. The only tool (besides BC) I found that supports verifying
S/MIME RSASSA-PSS signatures is a recent version of openssl.

According to the openssl documentation, this requires openssl >= 1.1.0.

openssl cms -verify -in email.eml -CAfile root.pem

This only works with the openssl cms command and not with the openssl
smime command.